# DHTML flydown menu not working in IE7

Tags: javascript, css

We just redesigned one of our sites at work with our new CMS and are having issues with the DHTML flydown menu in IE7 and IE6.

http://www.ohiomagazine.com/Main/Home.aspx

If you test it in IE7, you will see that the flydown is hidden behind the content below it. My coworker seems to think that there is something wrong with the CSS, while I believe it has to do with the CMS's god-awful JavaScript. The point is, neither of us know where to start and need a little help from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make the z-index of container div of the menu higher than the other divs. Here is an example. ("position:relative" is also needed.)

```
#menuwrapper
{
z-index:2;
position:relative;
}

#otherdiv1
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}

#otherdiv2
{
position:relative;
z-index:1;
}
```